# Oracle regexp_substr, regexp_replace

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I need to extract a substring via the oracles `regexp_substr` method.

So far I use

```
select regexp_substr('TD_SCHEMANEU_576','[^TD_]+[a-zA-Z]') from dual
;
```

which works fine, since it returns the expected sub string between 'TD_' && '_576':

```
SCHEMANEU
```

But if the the source string doesn't contain the string 'TD_'
the regex returns any string instead of `null`

The following returns `abc` instead of null

```
select regexp_substr('abc_def_ghi1024','[^TD_]+[a-zA-Z]') from dual
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[^TD_]` means "any character, except a `T`, a `D` or `_`".

You might want to use `REGEX_REPLACE` and capturing groups:

```
REGEX_REPLACE('TD_SCHEMANEU_576',
              'TD_([a-zA-Z]+)',
              '\1')
```

The `\1` is a backreference, pointing to what is in the first capturing group, ie the first set of parenthesis in the regex.

Comment: Are capturing groups supported by Oracle10g? I'm getting an error: 
`Error at line ... Command: '\1') `

Comment: I can't test myself, but [it seems like it should](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#SQLRF06302)...

Comment: @My-Name-Is: I take it you are using `regex_replace` and not `regex_substr`, right?